# Nginx gives a 404 for multiple flask apps under same domain

Tags: flask, uwsgi, flask-restful, nginx-config

I am trying to run a flask web app and a flask restful api on the same domain.
They both run fine, when they are run alone.
I am not using `venv`.

However, when I try to run them under a same domain, Nginx throws an error - 404, not found. Also, `localhost/` runs the web-app fine without errors but `localhost/web` and `localhost/rest` gives a 404.

The `request.url` prints `http://localhost/web` and `http://localhost/rest` but request is not being sent to flask server responsible for `/rest', it seems, as no data is logged for the second server (the restful api). All logged data is for the 1st server (the web app) only.

```
#Nginx.conf:

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;   

    location /web {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/webproject/web_uwsgi.sock;
    }    

    location /api {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/restproject/rest_api_uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

```
#webproject.ini                    #restproject.ini
[uwsgi]                            [uwsgi]
vhost = true                       vhost = true
project = webproject               project = restproject
base = /var/www/                   base = /var/www/
chdir = %(base)%(project)          chdir = %(base)%(project)
wsgi-file = run.py                 wsgi-file = api.py
callable = app                     callable = ap
mount = /webproject = app          mount = /restproject = ap
manage-script-name = true          manage-script-name = true
plugins = python                   plugins = python
socket = /var/www/webproject/%n.   socksocket = /var/www/restproject/%n.sock
chmod-socket    = 666              chmod-socket    = 666
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log      logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I forgot to restart nginx - `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`. Things are running pretty well now.

Comment: This is a useful config setup... even if it is a poor question ;)